# Samba share gives The network path was not found

Tags: linux, windows, samba, network-share

I have a problem with a samba share on a Linux server. When I try to open the share in Windows with `\\server_name\share` then I get an error:

> Windows cannot access \server_name\share
>
> Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a
>   problem with your network. To try to identify and resolve network
>   problems, click Diagnose.
>
> Error code: 0x80070035 
>   The network path was not found.

However, I can open the share without any problem with IP address `\\aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd\share`

I tried several stuff to delete cached credentials, e.g. `net use * /DELETE`. The server is not listed in Credential Manager, so there is nothing I could delete.

Any other hints to get it working?

Note, the share was accessible for **guest only**, this was working fine. Due to changed security policies I tired to change the samba share accordingly (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489869/allow-ad-group-to-access-samba-share) - this is not working yet. I reverted back all changes in samba config, however it does not work anymore, even though the configuration is exactly the same as it was before when it was working.

The Linux server has 4 shares. 3 of them I did not touch at all. But non of these 4 shares are working, so I assume there might be some kind of "network share cached data"

Comment: Can you `ping <server_name>`? Since it is using with the IP address, this looks like a name lookup issue.

Comment: @Thomas, ping is working fine, I don't think it's a lookup issue,

Comment: Can you post a gist of the full smb.conf.  Also check that it contians `netbios name = server_name` (or the equivelant non-example hostname) this should go in the `[global]` section.

Comment: @v25, netbios name is not set (i.e. it defaults to the host name which should be fine). The smb.conf content you can see in the linked question. Anyway, I requested a restore from backup, it is just a virtual test server. I know this is cheating but it is the fastest ways to start again from scratch.